# Linq condition "where id=List<Item> newList" how to achieve

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<string>resultList=new List<string>();
List<string>allID=new List<string>();
allID.Add("a1");
allID.Add("a2");
allID.Add("a3");
allID.Add("a4");
allID.Add("a5");
allID.Add("a6");
List<string>selectedID=new List<string>();
selectedID.Add("1");
selectedID.Add("3");
selectedID.Add("5");
resultList=(from a in allID where a.Contains(**one of the ID form selectedID**) select a).ToList();
```

Can tell me the working version?

Comment: hi (bro / sis who put the negative vote), if you know the answer and it is too easy, can give me the url or link or keywords to search in google?

Comment: clarification: `a1 == 1` or not?

Comment: Can you provide the expected result for `resultList`?  Your description is a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if each `a` exactly matches an entry inside by `selectedID`, use:

```
(from a in allID where selectedID.Contains(a) select a).ToList()
```

This would not return any matches with your example code.

---

If you are wanting to check if each string `a` contains the contents of *any* entry in `selectedID`, use:

```
(from a in allID
 where selectedID.Any(s => a.Contains(s))
 select a).ToList()
```

This would return `{ "a1", "a3", "a5" }`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
resultList = 
    (from a in allID 
     where selectedID.Any(s => ("a" + s) == a)
     select a)
    .ToList();
```

It will return `allID` items which are also in `selectedID` (with some formatting adjustments).

Answer (score 1):

```
resultList = allID.Where(x => selectedID.Select(s => "a" + s).Contains(x))
                  .ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

One more. Linq is cool :)

To check if allID contains the contents of any entry in selectedID

```
resultList = allID.Where(all => selectedID.Any(select => all.Contains(select))).ToList();
```

resultList would contain { "a1", "a3", "a5" }